# Ensuring that if one of two statements fail the end result will be no change for both statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, setter

#### Background

We have this code in our project for reading and writing from/to a row in our database

```
@property
def title_str(self) -> str:
    return self._title_str

@title_str.setter
def title_str(self, i_new_title: str):
    self._title_str = i_new_title
    self._update(db.Schema.PhrasesTable.Cols.title, i_new_title)
```

where the setter updates both the model object as well as the database

#### Problem and Question

We're concerned that if one of these statements

```
self._title_str = i_new_title
self._update(db.Schema.PhrasesTable.Cols.title, i_new_title)
```

fail while the other one succeeds there will be an inconsistency between the value in the model object and the value in our database

How can we avoid this risk?

#### Speculation

Perhaps there is a way to make two Python statements "atomic" so that if one fails the other one is reverted, or is the approach here just to store the old values and write them back if we catch an exception?

---

Grateful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property
def title_str(self) -> str:
    return self._title_str

@title_str.setter
def title_str(self, i_new_title: str):
    try:
        self._update(db.Schema.PhrasesTable.Cols.title, i_new_title)
    except TheExceptionRaisedByYourDb:
        pass
    else:  # there was no exception
        self._title_str = i_new_title
```

Use a `try ... except ... else` block and do only set the property in the Python object if setting it in the database has succeeded.